# Mobile development - different browser height

Tags: jquery, mobile

I'm developing simple mobile app using jquery mobile.
I'm experiencing strage behavor - the HTML renders differently every refresh/post.
I've detected the following symptom that may be the cause:
alert($(window).height()) 
gives me differnet values when I'm browsing through the address bar and through refresh button. It also gives different values if I'm reaccessing the pages through the same approch(like trying 10 times accessing the same page through address bar)
any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: The difference is the height of the address bar. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Nothing special. I'm hiding the address bar using jquery mobile. Is there any way to fix it? furthur more - sometimes the height is less the half - so I'm not sure it's just that